# _firebase2.default.database.ref is not a function

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to React Native and doing a project following some online tutorials. In given step, I have created a Firebase database (also added some dummy data and set a standard rule). In my React Native project, to fetch data after user being authenticated from Firebase, I'm doing following action :

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
export const loadInitialContacts = () =>
{
    const {currentUser} = firebase.auth();

    return (dispatch) => {
        firebase.database.ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/people`)
            .on('value', snapshot => {
                dispatch({type: 'INITIAL_FETCH', payload: snapshot.val()});
            });
    };
};
```

I'm calling the above method from my list view Component :

```
componentWillMount()
{
    this.props.loadInitialContacts();
}
```

Authentication to Firebase pass successfully, at the time of fetching data from Firebase it throws `exception` :

> Error: TypeError: TypeError: _firebase2.default.database.ref is not a function

What I'm doing wrong?

Looking into the `package.json`, I'm on this following version :

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^5.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "^0.55.4",
    ...
  },
```

Comment: try `firebase.database().ref`

Comment: instead of `firebase.database.ref`

Comment: Thank you! That clears the given error!

Comment: Unfortunately, the above call anyway returns me null even when I have some dummy record added to the database.

Comment: It looks like `.on('value', snapshot => {` never pass successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar error. 
My original code was:

```
    const rootRef = firebase.database.ref().child('react');
```

However, I changed it to

```
    const rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('react');
```

and it worked.

> Change firebase.database().ref from firebase.database.ref

Comment: Do you happen to know where we can find modern day documentation on how you got your answer to work for you in your environment?